# Text editor with function calls references

Tags: text-editor

In the DOS era I used a text editor (forgot the name) which had a outstanding feature.
Whenever i was over a function call, hitting a key combination it took me to the function definition. Also, when I was in the function definition, I was able to see all calls to that function. Something like

This function is called from:

- function1, line 154, source1.c
- function3, line 500, source2.c

I loved this feature and I miss it. Is there any actual editor with a feature like this?

I'm on windows, but if I can get this function, i'm capable of buy a mac :-D (kidding)

Update
I'm using php. My example was with .c files because I used that editor with c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent versions of **Kate**, KDE's advanced text editor, come with a plugin called **ctags** that does exactly what you want. Since KDE 4, you can install some KDE programs in Windows thanks to the [KDE on Windows](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwindows.kde.org%2F&ei=0zTxSpGTD6OQmwPhtsGXDQ&usg=AFQjCNHCd19df4G5eVbn38YCdgEksCjAzg) project. Kate is one of those you can install.

Once you have launched it please go to *Settings -> Configure Kate...*, choose *Plugins* from the left pane and enable the **ctags** plugin.

Comment: ok, I'll take a look.
Does it support utf-8 and sintax highlight for php/html/css?

Comment: It supports UTF-8, and as I recall, syntax highlighting, but I don't know if it has presets for those languages (I'd imagine so though, they are pretty common)

Comment: It has presets for a ton of languages including markup languages. It supports themes, that is you can choose what colors should be used for highlighting various elements. It supports both UNIX and Windows end-of-line. It supports sessions. Basically it's another thermonuclear text editor like emacs but a little lighter.

Comment: jajajaj, ok, downloading. This will take a while

Answer (score 0):

Since your example returns function call results from multiple files, you probably want not a simple text editor but rather an **IDE** (Integrated Development Environment) for C. What you describe is a standard feature probably present in every modern-day C(++) IDE. From my personal experience, **Visual Studio** (e.g. [Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VC/)) supports both "Go to definition" and "Find references".

Comment: well, actualy I'm using php. My example was wit .c files because I used that editor with c

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, this is possible on just about every modern editor. To name a few alternatives in case you're still looking:

ctags has been mentioned. cscope improves on ctags by actually parsing the code so that it can distinguish between, say, the search string in a comment and the search string in actual code. Not sure how it handles callbacks in PHP, since you guys just pass in the function name as a string, right?

vim integrates with ctags and cscope, as does emacs.

vim, I believe, also has a built-in ability to go from a call to the definition, and (implemented as simple string searching) to cycle through calls of a function. It also has the neat feature of querying documentation (by default, man pages, but configurable to other things) on a function name. These are one one-keystroke commands. vim is available on Win32 either as a text-mode client or a GUI app (called gvim).